# Jar Class not found upon execution

Tags: java, jar, jms

I am trying to use the javax.jms library: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/package-summary.html, for which I have downloaded the jar: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjms111sourcesjar.htm

Specifically, I am trying to use the MessageListener and Message classes, which I know to be in there based on the Jar decompilation. I put this jar file next to my java file, so that the file structure looks like this:

```
myDir
    -|jms.jar
    -|Main.java
```

Main.java:

```
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Message;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message msg) {
              
            }
        };
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I can compile this using javac -cp jms.jar Main.java from inside myDir. This creates Main.class. However, when I run java Main, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener
```

This would lead me to believe that MessageListener is not included in the jar, but it is and the file structure is javax/jms/MessageListener checks out. What dumb mistake am I making?

When I compile without -cp js, it fails, saying:

```
error: package javax.jms does not exist
```

thus, at least the compiler is looking in the jar.

Comment: Did you try it with the -cp .;jms.jar option so the java program knows to look in the jar file?

Comment: when I add .; it doesn't compile -bash: jms.jar: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 Mistakes

1: Credit to @NormR, .:jms.jar (or .; for Windows I surmise)
2: Link jar while executing. Therefore, the commands should've been:

```
javac -cp .:jms.jar Main.java
java -cp .:jms.jar Main
```